# Why does xmlDocument Load throw timeout error?

Tags: c#

I use System.Xml.XmlDocument to load a file,then wait a minute throw the timeout error. Curiously, the code can work in another project.

1. I try Use System.IO.File.Open this file, it's no problem.
2. XmlDocument.LoadXml() is throw the error too.

   ```
   System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
   doc.Load(@"D:\work\xxx.svg");
   ```

add:

I see the stacktrace info, it's WebException, error code System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse().

So the XmlDocument.Load() method is think of my filepath as url, but i don't understand why it work in another project is all right

Comment: What is the size of the file you try to load? Is it a valid XML format? `System.IO.File.Open` does not load the whole file into the memory, whereas `XmlDocument.Load` loads the entire content.

Comment: You can't get a decent guess without showing the exception details, including the stack trace.  You shouldn't be doing this in the first place, google "c# svg parser" to find a decent library.

Comment: @user2190035  i use this code in another test project, it's work.Certainly Is it a valid XML format. And i use XmlDocument.LoadXml(string xml) this method, it's throw timeout error too, not another error

Comment: When the same code works in another project then you have other side effects in your current project. Maybe the xxx.svg file is accessed by some other code. We can only guess...

Answer (score 2):

I follow the stacktrace, saw the problem:

> [XmlException: Open external DTD
>   "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd": An error occurred
>   while the operation timed out. ]

Then I add XMLreaderSetting:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore;
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(@"D:\\111.txt", settings);
xmlDoc.Load(reader);
```

They final work.

But I am curious why in another project is no problem.

I hope this answer can help another with the same difficulties.